# Problem understanding const assignment from props in context of Wordpress block development

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm not sure if this is my lack of understanding of JavaScript, or React, or Wordpress modifications to React, but what is this doing?

```
export default function MyFunction( props ) {
        const {
                attributes: {
                    foo1,
                    foo2
                },
                setAttributes,
        } = props;
```

I thought it was taking React props and creating two `const`s scoped to `MyFunction`: "attributes" and "setAttributes". But, later on, if I do something like

```
   return (
      <>
        <Fragment>
            <div>{ foo1 }</div> // this works fine
            <div>{ attributes }</div> // this says "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: attributes"
        </Fragment>
      </>
    );
```

I don't understand why I *can* reference foo1 without going attributes.foo1; and I don't understand why I *can't* reference attributes. So, I'm clearly not understanding what seems like a "simple" assignment. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have drilled passed `attributes` when doing the object spread so you only assigned the inner values. There are a few ways you can solve this

```
export default function MyFunction( props ) {
        const {
                attributes: {
                    foo1,
                    foo2
                },
                attributes, // grab attributes too
                setAttributes,
        } = props;
```

```
export default function MyFunction( props ) {
        const {
                attributes,
                setAttributes,
        } = props;
        const { foo1, foo2 } = attributes; // grab the values after
```

Or you simply can just grab attributes like above and use dot notation `attributes.foo1`